# HTML page larger font size on iPad Safari

Tags: html, css, ipad, fonts, font-size

I would like to know why I am getting a larger font size on Safari on iPad compared to any browser on Mac, even Safari. And how to solve it!

This is a Wordpress forum and the screenshots attached show 1 post. Take a look at the date: "April 18, 2012". It is larger in the 2nd screenshot (iPad) than the 1st. Why is that? There is no CSS is play here - it is all commented out.

Safari Mac:
[image: Safari Mac]

Safari iPad:
[image: Safari iPad]

FYI Im not using any special iPad meta tags & JS is disabled as well.

The HTML for this part in question is as follows:

```
<div class="post-7 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-two tag-tag1 tag-tag2 tag-tag3" id="post-7">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to Pellentesque elementum nulla mattis elit ullamcorper nec viverra felis mattis" href="http://foscavir.local.etalented.co.uk/blogs/pellentesque-elementum-nulla-mattis-elit-ullamcorper-nec-viverra-felis-mattis/">Pellentesque elementum nulla mattis elit ullamcorper nec viverra felis mattis</a></h2>

        <div class="entry-meta">
            April 18, 2012          </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </div>
```

Comment: If there's no CSS involved, then it's the default styles which are used.

Comment: Correct. However I have to use a font-size 2 pixels smaller to achieve the same size on iPad for .entry-meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you could try is: [-webkit-text-size-adjust](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-text-size-adjust)

**Edit:** set it to 100% like proposed in comments.

Comment: Thanks. I have applied that directly to .entry-meta, but no change on iPad. I tried -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;

Comment: No change with that unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in implementing that. That does work. Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry, I was late with the comments. It really should be set to 100%. That's what is done eg. in HTML5 Mobile Boilerplate. Glad you've got it working.